# How to give a Linux user sudo access?

Tags: linux, sudo

I am trying to give sudo access to one of my users. What should I type in my terminal?

Comment: This question is obviously helping a lot of people and you should consider re-opening it.

Comment: If you like to reopen the question you should provide additional details that qualify it as a valid according the rules  in the help center.

Comment: This question should be moved to the correct site rather then closed.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You need run `visudo` and in the editor that it opens write:

```
igor    ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

That line grants all permissions to user `igor`.

If you want permit to run only some commands, you need to list them in the line:

```
igor    ALL=(ALL) /bin/kill, /bin/ps
```

Comment: What would be the reason if one carried out the above, but the user (in this case `igor`) still did not have full sudo access (ie. can issue `sudo ls` but not `sudo mount -a`)?

Comment: @puk it depends on the commands that you listed in /etc/sudoers; when you wrote `ALL`, user can run all commands

Answer (score 58):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11094847) will do what you need, although usually you don't add specific usernames to `sudoers`. Instead, you have a **group** of sudoers and just add your user to that group when needed. This way you don't need to use `visudo` more than once when giving `sudo` permission to users.

If you're on Ubuntu, the group is most probably already set up and called `admin`:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
```

...

```
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

On other distributions, like Arch and some others, it's usually called `wheel` and you may need to set it up: [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sudo)

> To give users in the wheel group full root privileges when they precede a command with "sudo", uncomment the following line:
>   %wheel  ALL=(ALL) ALL

Also note that on most systems `visudo` will read the `EDITOR` environment variable or default to using `vi`. So you can try to do `EDITOR=vim visudo` to use `vim` as the editor.

To add a user to the group you should run (as root):

```
# usermod -a -G groupname username
```

where `groupname` is your group (say, `admin` or `wheel`) and `username` is the username (say, `john`).

Answer (score -3):

Edit `/etc/sudoers` file either manually or using the visudo application.
Remember: System reads `/etc/sudoers` file from top to the bottom, so you could overwrite a particular setting by putting the next one below.
So to be on the safe side - define your access setting at the bottom.

Comment: If you edit it manually, you can damage it and corrupt your sudo access. No reason not to use `visudo`.

Comment: Agree with last comment. Also, consider add commands as examples.

Comment: @ripper234 there are multiple reasons, when writing IAC you are not able to run a cli utility to configure just one server... you are forced to do it manually...