# -bash: /bin/crtmqm: Permission denied

Tags: ibm-mq

Any help or help would be greatly appreciated it!!
I am running on Redhat Enterprise 7.3
I ran the following:
$usermod -aG wheel jadeite1000

My userid is: jadeite1000
cd /opt/mqm/bin
I ran this command to tried to create queue "TESTQM" but get error:

```
$sudo crtmqm TESTQM
```

error:
AM17877E: You are not authorized to perform the requested operation.

Comment: what is the output of "ls -la /bin/crtmqm"? My guess is that the user you are trying to execute the command with does not have execute rights on that binary

Comment: just do `sudo crtmqm TESTQM`. If don't have a sudo access, please follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11094826/how-to-give-a-linux-user-sudo-access

Comment: I believe you need to be in the mqm group. Can you try that?

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to the user used to issue the crtmqm command not being in the mqm group. See the  article here https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=objects-authority-administer-mq-aix-linux-windows